# SVG height element not dynamic?

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to make the svg dynamically resize depending on the browser size.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script type= 'text/javascript' src ='../libraries/d3/d3.v3.min.js'> </script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>CIQ workflow</title>

<style type='text/css'>

    svg{
        width:80%;
        height:80%;
        background:green;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<script >
    var canvas = d3.select('body').append('svg')

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

1. When I view this particular code in browser it is updating dynamically width wise, but not height wise. Why?
2. What is the advantage of using the view box and then making those values dynamic in comparison to this methodology? Why is correct way to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) Try adding

```
    html{
        height:100%; 
    } 

    body{
        height:100%;
    }
```

to your style and your SVG will now style appropriately. What's happening is that your page's `document.body` is being sized to fit whatever contents are placed in it. It's essentially doing this:

```
    Check inner DOM elements to determine height
        --> Sees SVG element and tries to size it based on that.
            --> SVG element has no height set so set body to some browser-specified
                body min-height
                ==> Onward to SVG element! 
                    --> SVG height = 80% body min-height.
```

You can also set the body height to something else, like 500px (or even 10px if you want to override the min-height).

(2) I'm not very familiar with using a ViewBox but based on reading [this w3.org description](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/coords.html#ViewBoxAttribute) it seems like if you'll be doing mainly transforms and scaling, then using a ViewBox would be simpler since you'd be replicating what a ViewBox does.

**Update:** Apparently, Safari & Chrome work fine without the `html{height:100%}` style above, but not Firefox so make sure you add that in too.

Comment: Hi, your solution is some what correct. The difference is you have to apply the same property to the HTML tag also. Then it worked. The reason is that SVG tag is inline-non replaceable element for which you can't add height and width property. Please add that to the solution for the users.

Comment: Ah, turns out that leaving out the html part works in Safari and Chrome but not Firefox. Thanks for pointing it out. I've updated the answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

One other thing you can do is to use absolute positioning:

```
svg {
    position: absolute;
    width:80%;
    height:80%;
    background:green;
}
```

and you will get the size you want, but this may not be appropriate to your situation.

Comment: SVG are inline, not block please check. They are inline non-replaceable to be specific.

Answer (score 0):

If You want your inline SVG to fill the full browser window you can use the viewBox with Javascript as in the example as shown below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title>SVG Fills Window Screen</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body style='overflow:hidden'>
<div id="svgDiv" style='position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;background-color:lightgreen;'>
<svg id="mySVG">
<circle id="myCircle" cx="120" cy="180" r="40" fill="red" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
<rect id="myRect"  x="220" y="250" width="60" height="60" fill="blue" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"  />
<ellipse id="myEllipse1" cx="900" cy="1200" rx="150" ry="75" fill="yellow"  stroke="black" stroke-width="2"  />
<ellipse id="myEllipse2" cx="1900" cy="90" rx="150" ry="75" fill="yellow"  stroke="black" stroke-width="2"  />
<ellipse id="myEllipse3" cx="3900" cy="2200" rx="150" ry="75" fill="yellow"  stroke="black" stroke-width="2"  />
<text x="50%" y="50%"  text-anchor="middle" font-size="150">SVG image fills window screen</text>
</svg>
</div>

<script id=myScript>
//--onload, onresize----
function sizeFull()
{
    var svgW=window.innerWidth
    var svgH=window.innerHeight
    var bb=mySVG.getBBox()
    var bbx=bb.x
    var bby=bb.y
    var bbw=bb.width
    var bbh=bb.height
    mySVG.setAttribute("viewBox",bbx+" "+bby+" "+bbw+" "+bbh )
    mySVG.setAttribute("width",svgW)
    mySVG.setAttribute("height",svgH)
}
document.addEventListener("onload",sizeFull(),false)
window.onresize=sizeFull
</script>

</body>

</html>
```